# Google Cloud - Connection timout, TLS - handshake

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, timeout, iot, google-cloud-iot

I am developing a project based on the `Google Cloud IoT Core platform`. I want to **publish** telemetry data using the **GSM module (SIM7020 - NB-IoT)**.

However, the connection time `(TLS handshake)` takes **a lot of time** (> 10 seconds) and the connection is broken by the Google server.

What is the timeout handshake?

Can I **extend** this timeout in `IoT Core settings`?. Anyone have an idea how to work around this problem with slow connections?

best regards

Comment: This error means that your IoT device cannot connect to the other end. Extending the timeout will just mean waiting longer for failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bound to UDP, you may try out [cloud-iot-coap-proxy](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-coap-proxy). A DTLS PSK handshake, if that complies to your security requirements, is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You use SSL/TLS to establish a secure connection between the 2 points. To achieve this connection you need to complete a successful handshake between these points. If this handshake fails for example in your scenario because of timeout then the SSL/TLS couldn’t complete the handshake during this period. You can find more information about SSl/TLS from the organization Internet Engineering Task Force (ietf). [Handshake from ietf](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.3), [timeout from ietf](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7925#page-38).

For your information SSL/TLS is for TCP and DTLS for UDP.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to Google support, it turned out that the only solution was to run your own virtual machine or use CoAP and communication over UDP. I decided to change cloud hosting to competitive.